# Assign group number based on time series data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, time-series

I would like to group `df` by `ID`, then group rows where `State` starts with `1` and ends with the first `0` as one group(if there is no `0` at the end, as shown in the expected output below, the `1`s will be considered as one group). If there are consecutive `1`s in a row, then proceed to the next value until a `0` is found. The rows starting with the first `1`s and ending with the first `0` belong to one group. If consecutive `0`s are observed, we are not interested (except for the first one, which should be the end of a group). Then I want to assign the same group number to rows in each group. In the example of `df`, `ID` has 2 values - `32` and `64`, they are considered as independent groups.

`df`:

```
        ID  Timestamp               Value   State
103177  64  2010-09-21 23:13:21.090 21.5    1.0
252019  64  2010-09-22 00:44:14.890 21.5    1.0
271381  64  2010-09-22 00:44:15.890 21.5    0.0
268939  64  2010-09-22 00:44:17.890 23.0    0.0
259875  64  2010-09-22 00:44:18.440 23.0    1.0
18870   64  2010-09-22 00:44:19.890 24.5    1.0
205910  32  2010-09-22 00:44:23.440 24.5    1.0
103865  32  2010-09-22 01:04:33.440 23.5    0.0
152281  32  2010-09-22 01:27:01.790 22.5    1.0
138988  32  2010-09-22 02:18:52.850 21.5    0.0
```

reproducible example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {103177: 64,
  252019: 64,
  271381: 64,
  268939: 64,
  259875: 64,
  18870: 64,
  205910: 32,
  103865: 32,
  152281: 32,
  138988: 32},
 'Timestamp': {103177: Timestamp('2010-09-21 23:13:21.090000'),
  252019: Timestamp('2010-09-22 00:44:14.890000'),
  271381: Timestamp('2010-09-22 00:44:15.890000'),
  268939: Timestamp('2010-09-22 00:44:17.890000'),
  259875: Timestamp('2010-09-22 00:44:18.440000'),
  18870: Timestamp('2010-09-22 00:44:19.890000'),
  205910: Timestamp('2010-09-22 00:44:23.440000'),
  103865: Timestamp('2010-09-22 01:04:33.440000'),
  152281: Timestamp('2010-09-22 01:27:01.790000'),
  138988: Timestamp('2010-09-22 02:18:52.850000')},
 'Value': {103177: 21.5,
  252019: 21.5,
  271381: 21.5,
  268939: 23.0,
  259875: 23.0,
  18870: 24.5,
  205910: 24.5,
  103865: 23.5,
  152281: 22.5,
  138988: 21.5},
 'State': {103177: 1.0,
  252019: 1.0,
  271381: 0.0,
  268939: 0.0,
  259875: 1.0,
  18870: 1.0,
  205910: 1.0,
  103865: 0.0,
  152281: 1.0,
  138988: 0.0}})

df
```

Expected output:

```
        ID  Timestamp               Value   State   Group
103177  64  2010-09-21 23:13:21.090 21.5    1.0     1
252019  64  2010-09-22 00:44:14.890 21.5    1.0     1
271381  64  2010-09-22 00:44:15.890 21.5    0.0     1
268939  64  2010-09-22 00:44:17.890 23.0    0.0     -
259875  64  2010-09-22 00:44:18.440 23.0    1.0     2   (* `State` only has `1`, didn't end with `0`.)
18870   64  2010-09-22 00:44:19.890 24.5    1.0     2   (* `State` only has `1`, didn't end with `0`.)
205910  32  2010-09-22 00:44:23.440 24.5    1.0     3   * New `ID`, thus `Group` increases by 1.
103865  32  2010-09-22 01:04:33.440 23.5    0.0     3
152281  32  2010-09-22 01:27:01.790 22.5    1.0     4
138988  32  2010-09-22 02:18:52.850 21.5    0.0     4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.where` with mask to get 1 where there is a change of ID or there is 1 in status and not in the previous row. then use `cumsum` to increment the value. For the 0 you want to get -, you can do it after, using `loc` with another mask.

```
df['gr'] = np.cumsum( 
    np.where(df['ID'].ne(df['ID'].shift())  #new ID
            | (df['Status'].eq(1) #status 1
               & df['Status'].ne(df['Status'].shift())), # previous status not the same
             1, 0))

# I would rather use np.nan than '-' to keep numeric values but up to you
df.loc[df['Status'].eq(0) 
       & df['Status'].eq(df['Status'].shift()), 'gr'] = '-'

print(df)
        ID               Timestamp  Value  Status gr
103177  64 2010-09-21 23:13:21.090   21.5     1.0  1
252019  64 2010-09-22 00:44:14.890   21.5     1.0  1
271381  64 2010-09-22 00:44:15.890   21.5     0.0  1
268939  64 2010-09-22 00:44:17.890   23.0     0.0  -
259875  64 2010-09-22 00:44:18.440   23.0     1.0  2
18870   64 2010-09-22 00:44:19.890   24.5     1.0  2
205910  32 2010-09-22 00:44:23.440   24.5     1.0  3
103865  32 2010-09-22 01:04:33.440   23.5     0.0  3
152281  32 2010-09-22 01:27:01.790   22.5     1.0  4
138988  32 2010-09-22 02:18:52.850   21.5     0.0  4
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's try:

```
# identify the groups within each ID
groups = (1-df.iloc[::-1].Status).groupby(df['ID']).cumsum().iloc[::-1]

# mask out the single-zero groups:
single_zero = s.groupby([df['ID'],s]).transform('size').ne(1)

# use groupby().ngroup() to identify the expected output
df['Group'] = df[single_zero].groupby([df['ID'],s], sort=False).ngroup() + 1
```

Output:

```
        ID               Timestamp  Value  Status  Group
103177  64 2010-09-21 23:13:21.090   21.5     1.0    1.0
252019  64 2010-09-22 00:44:14.890   21.5     1.0    1.0
271381  64 2010-09-22 00:44:15.890   21.5     0.0    1.0
268939  64 2010-09-22 00:44:17.890   23.0     0.0    NaN
259875  64 2010-09-22 00:44:18.440   23.0     1.0    2.0
18870   64 2010-09-22 00:44:19.890   24.5     1.0    2.0
205910  32 2010-09-22 00:44:23.440   24.5     1.0    3.0
103865  32 2010-09-22 01:04:33.440   23.5     0.0    3.0
152281  32 2010-09-22 01:27:01.790   22.5     1.0    4.0
138988  32 2010-09-22 02:18:52.850   21.5     0.0    4.0
```

---

**Option 2**: Slightly different approach with less groupby:

```
groups = df.groupby(['ID', df.iloc[::-1].Status.eq(0)
                             .groupby(df['ID']).cumsum()
                             .iloc[::-1]],
                    sort=False                    
                   ).ngroup() + 1

single_zero = groups.groupby(groups).transform('size').eq(1)

df['Group'] = (groups - single_zero.cumsum()).mask(single_zero)
```